# tipos de dados dentro do vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

tenho uma macro que faz uma conversão, ele traz um txt de largura fixa converte para excel
e salva em csv. o que acontece é que eu preciso que a ultima coluna seja salva com formato txto
porque trata de numero de contrato e quando pela quantidade de caracteres o excel transforma em "16752+52" e no meio dessas conversoes eu perco estes dados. como eu faço para salvar os dados que eu puxei do txt como texto, mesmo quando no campo só tem numeros?

abaixo meu codigo:

````
If Dir("F:\arquivo") <> "" Then
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="F:\arquivo", _
        Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array( _
        Array(0, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(76, _
        1), Array(87, 1), Array(92, 1), Array(93, 1), Array(104, 1), Array(107, 1), Array(113, 1), _
        Array(125, 1), Array(145, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("Q5").Select
      ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
    dirCopia = "F:\conersao_ok\"
    nomeCopia = "arquivo_ok"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
dirCopia + nomeCopia, _
FileFormat:=xlCSV, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
Workbooks("arquivo_ok.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
End If
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que há duas maneiras de resolver seu problema.

1. Na coluna em que os dados precisam ser convertidos de número para texto, você pode aplicar a função `CStr`, que converte valores em uma célula para texto dentro de uma estrutura de repetição `Do While...Loop` ou similar, para que percorra cada célula e faça a conversão.
2. Ao invés de converter para texto, você pode usar a função `NumberFormat` e aplicar uma formatação de número customizada para a coluna específica que você quer formatar. A funcionalidade dessa função é parecida como quando se formata um número direto na planilha.

Espero que ajude.